# PySpark Application hangs forever in client mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cluster-computing

The script runs fine when you run it locally with spark-submit, currently there are 4 slave nodes and when you attempt to run the pyspark script as an application in client mode as follows

```sh
./bin/spark-submit \
--master spark://<master ip>:7077 \
--deploy-mode  client \
--files /home/scalability_scripts/amazon_reviews/amazon_review_full_csv/train.csv  \
/home/scalability_scripts/NaiveBayes.py --train /home/scalability_scripts/amazon_reviews/amazon_review_full_csv/train.csv --limit 1000000
```

the code hangs for ever and this is the last message shown

```sh
9/07/16 03:42:12 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
19/07/16 03:42:12 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/home/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-warehouse').
19/07/16 03:42:12 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/home/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-warehouse'.
19/07/16 03:42:12 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
```

The cluster manager is the spark standalone cluster manager and all the slave nodes have python installed with necessary modules. Does this issue have anything to do with specifying the files ? Or am I missing any additional
config ?

p.s i found the following error in stderr in spark ui when it application hangs

```sh
Spark Executor Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211//bin/java" "-cp" "/home/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/:/home/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=37281" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@server:37281" "--executor-id" "5142" "--hostname" "153.64.25.60" "--cores" "8" "--app-id" "app-20190716015703-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@153.64.25.60:32921"
========================================

Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 6970@39054
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
19/07/16 02:33:06 WARN Utils: Your hostname, 39054 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 153.64.25.60 instead (on interface ens160)
19/07/16 02:33:06 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
19/07/16 02:33:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/07/16 02:33:06 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:64)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to server/153.64.25.113:37281
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: server/153.64.25.113:37281
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is --limit 1000000? are you trying to limit the output?

Comment: @user805 that is to limit the number of training samples (viz input) completely unrelated to the output, i am just attempting to run a pyspark application on a spark cluster so that it actually uses all the nodes. currently, it only runs locally on master.

Comment: Are firewalls enabled? Spark is going to pick a few random ports... As you can see by it unable to reach `153.64.25.113:37281`. Also, a hostname of just `server` isn't a good idea